# How can I check if in post_type page category view from a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

The method `is_category()` seem only to work in the theme files, but when used in a plugin, no value is returned.

I want this plugin to display content that should only relate to `post_type->page` category view. EG

```
if( is_category() )
  do_this();
```

How can I do category check from the plugin?

---

The plugin should check that it is in category view and display data accordingly.

[image: image of desired process]

Comment: This question is **NOT** reproducible. Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). While i understand that debugging your plugin could potentially be frustrating but simply by providing a single function and saying it does not work, people can not help you. `is_category` works from my plugin so does other solutions i provided you with. The bug must be elsewhere in you code which you didn't provide.

Comment: The **example code** provided is just that, hence the reason **EG** is clearly written before. The **example code** is not the problem. It is that there is no method for a **plugin** to determine when the page in view is a category.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Nadai.
There is 1 solution how to get the Category
use please

```
$category = get_queried_object();
echo $category->term_id;
```

if you are on

- page of the post, the object of the current post WP_Post on which
- page of the category, the WP_Term object of the current category
- author page, the WP_User object with user information
- page of the record type, the WP_Post_Type object

Tell please if it works for you...

Comment: Yes I had already tried that function, but it does not retrieve the object within the plugin. It works fin in the theme, but I am not working with a theme. After some research I have settled on `get_category_by_slug('cat-slug')` which returns the object. Just that I have to `parse_url()` of the current URL and strip slashes from the returned `[path]`. The problem is that there are potential inconsistencies due to URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Use action hook 'wp' which gets the full system object and then do the data output process within that hook. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/

**A concept (not actual)**

```php
add_action( 'wp', function() {
   $cat = get_queried_object();

   if( is_category() ) {
    add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar', function($widget) use ($cat) {
     $widget['name'] = '<h2>' . $cat->cat_name . '</h2>';
     return $widget;
    });
   }

});
```